# How to make a div at bottom if there is another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three divs.i want one div at bottom of the page.

```
<div id="abc">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
<div id="three">
</div>
```

`abc` is the header of the page.
`two` is the articles show on page.
`three` is the footer of the page.
i want div `three` at bottom of the page. if i don't have any articles then also `three` div has to show at the bottom of the page.`two` div will be empty at that time.if `there` are many articles when i scroll down to the end of the page at that time it has to show the `three` div.
please explain me.
thank you in advance.

Comment: can u make an image for example ?

Comment: Use clear :both; on footer div. Easyer to help if you had some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this nicely with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I've included two examples below. Hope this helps!

Here's a demo of how the footer is at the bottom when there's no content:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background: pink;
  height: 50px;
}

#footer {
  background: skyblue;
  height: 50px;
}

#articles {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="articles"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And here's a demo with the same styles, showing how the footer is pushed down when there's enough content:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background: pink;
  height: 50px;
}

#footer {
  background: skyblue;
  height: 50px;
}

#articles {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: auto;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="articles">
    <span>Article</span>
    <span>Article</span>
    <span>Article</span>
    <span>Article</span>
    <span>Article</span>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please tell me without using flex?because i have written the code already.i am new to css.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```css
body{
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
}
#abc{
  background:#000;  
  height:50px;
}
#two{
  background:#ff0;
  height:50px;
}
#three{
  background:#ff0000;
  height:50px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="abc">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
<div id="three">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

make `position: fixed` for div "three"

```css
#two { 
height: 1000px;
}
#three { 
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
background: red;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="abc">Some text
</div>
<div id="two">Some text
</div>
<div id="three">Some text
</div>
```

Comment: if i fix the position of the div then in mobile it is overriding the second div.that means on the top of the second div three div content is showing.my website is responsive.